# Are there recognized restrictions or categories for spoonerisms?

Tags: terminology, speech

I enjoy thinking up spoonerisms in my spare time and came up with "why, indeed" and "dyin' weed."

But I don't know if this can qualify as a spoonerism, because

1. although the sounds are switched, they are not the first sounds of each word
2. the "g" in dying is wiped out.

Would either of these disqualify my two phrases from being a spoonerism, and if not, are there special sub-categories for spoonerisms that aren't straightforward?

ETA: another possible subcategory might be "In-groups grin. Oops." Where sounds aren't swapped but rather the "gr" is shifted from one word to the next, as opposed to a more standard construction "See, well, we sell."

Comment: Care must be exhibited, I assume, as to not slip into a different tongue twisting mode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism#See_also

Comment: It's a rhyme, not a spoonerism.

Comment: If it looks like a spoonerism, sounds like a spoonerism .... Wikipedia allows for morpheme swap.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But only inside a safe house.

Comment: @Hot Licks  It certainly sounds spooneristic, even though strictly it fails Cambridge dictionary's definition.  We could, at this point 'invent' a special term for this extension of the idea and call it is 'spifted shoonerism'.  Although that tight murn the thole ting into a bit of a dig's donner.

Comment: This does not qualify as spoonerism if a sloonerism needs to create new meaning. You might hold it differently, but I don't see why anyone would use it that way. Anyway, this creation appears as meaningless as the infamous "green ideas". On the other hand, formally, it switches the fist sounds of the stressed syllables, so in that sense it would count in my book. The added rebracketing makes it less palpalable though.

Comment: @vectory Why was the dealer sad about what he found in his greenhouse? Why indeed.

Comment: [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/spoonerism-words-1692128#:~:text=Spoonerism%20or%20Slip%20of%20the%20Tongue,-Share&text=Dr.,level%20grammar%20and%20composition%20textbooks.&text=The%20term%20spoonerism%20is%20derived%20from%20the%20name%20of%20William%20A.) has a broad definition: << Peter Farb: Spooner . . . once said to a stranger who was occupying his personal pew in the college chapel: 'Excuse me, but I think you are occupewing my pie.' >> Not even an acceptable transposition. But fun.